# In C++ Good reasons for NOT using symmetrical memory management (i.e. new and delete)

Tags: c++, memory, qt

*I try to learn C++ and programming in general. Currently I am studying 
open source with help of UML. Learning is my hobby and great one too.*

My understanding of memory allocation in C++ is that it should be 
symmetrical. A class is responsible for its resources. If memory is 
allocated using new it should be returned using delete in the same 
class. It is like in a library you, the class, are responsibility for 
the books you have borrowed and you return them then you are done.

This, in my mind, makes sense. It makes memory management more 
manageable so to speak.

So far so good. The problem is that this is not how it works in the 
real world.

In Qt for instance, you create QtObjects with new and then hand over 
the ownership of the object to Qt. In other words you create QtObjects 
and Qt destroys them for you. Thus unsymmetrical memory management. 
Obviously the people behind Qt must have a good reason for doing this. 
It must be beneficial in some kind of way,

#### My questions is:

- What is the problem with Bjarne Stroustrups idea about a symmetrical 
  memory management contained within a class?
- What do you gain by splitting new and delete so you create an 
  object and destroy it in different classes like you do in Qt.
- Is it common to split new and delete and why in such case, in other 
  projects not involving Qt?

**Thanks for any help shedding light on this mystery!**

Comment: `In other words you create QtObjects and Qt destroys them for you` I do not know about Qt, but I know that C++ does not this for you. So you must keep the code tidy in order to avoid forgetting to delete objects (memory leak) or deleting them twice (unspecified behavior).

Answer (score 7):

In modern C++ you typically want to use the [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization (RAII)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) idiom. The idea is that any resource that you allocate should be wrapped into a class, and it should be deleted/closed/cleaned up by the class's destructor. A resource is anything that you need to de-allocate, close, or otherwise clean up when you are done with it. Most often a resource is memory, but it could be other things like files or network connections.

In some cases the wrapping class can be complex, representing some piece of program logic.  In most cases the wrapping class can be very simple, existing solely for the purpose of de-allocating the resource at the right time in the right way. An example of that is a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).

I haven't looked at Qt in a very long time. However, letting the user allocate an object, and pass a raw pointer into a library function that later de-allocates it is a rather outdated pattern. If the Qt function throws an exception before it has a chance to delete your object, you will inevitably have a memory leak. The object should be wrapped into a smart pointer, whose destructor will delete it automagically, including the case when an exception is thrown.

Comment: The **RAII** concept still applies, it is great to hear. At least I got 
that part right. But considering that std::shared_ptr<> is part of C++11 
the way of Qt is not outdated. Rather the opposite.

Comment: Wait, I was saying that passing a raw pointer into a function, that would have to delete it explicitly is outdated.  Passing smart pointers around is certainly not outdated. I don't know what Qt is doing these days.

Comment: I am junior so please no offence, but the shared object provided to the constructor of shared_ptr is not copied. You create the shared object, with **new**, then hand it over to shared_ptr.

Comment: Oh, no offence at all. :) The shared object is allocated immediately before constructing the shared_ptr, literally in the same statement `ptr = shared_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass)`, and then it is deleted by the shared_ptr's destructor when necessary. I suppose you can argue that this is not symmetric memory management, but I think it is pretty close to it.

Comment: Which is the odd wobbly bit The need for new outside shared_ptr. That part puzzles me. The purpose of the copy constructor is to omit this need. Is there objects that can't be copied ?

Comment: There are objects that are too big to be copied. For example if you are working with high resolution images, you don't want to have to keep copying a image buffer every time you need to pass it into a function.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me returning the ball, again. A huge resource is an 
argument for a _shallow copy versus deep copy_. I assume here that a 
huge resource would be wrapped into a class. I find it far fetched and 
silly but could it be a case of saving programmers from the need of 
creating a copy constructor in the first place? The cutting corner 
argument. For instance if the shared object is a structor.

Comment: Well a smart pointer does the shallow copy... It all depends on whether a memory buffer stays within your object or whether it needs to be passed to other objects.  And you are correct, wrapping your pointer data members into smart pointers can save you the need of writing a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> - What is the problem with Bjarne Stroustrups idea about a symmetrical memory management contained within a class?

In most cases, there is no problem at all with doing symmetrical memory management. This is also what the principle of [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) is based upon.
There are, however, always situations where the class that allocated some memory isn't the last one to need to reference that memory. Sometimes this can be resolved by passing the ownership (and thus the responsibility for deletion) on to another class. Sometimes it is not even clear who will be the last to reference a piece of memory. In those cases, garbage collection techniques like reference counting come in handy.

> - What do you gain by splitting new and delete so you create an object and destroy it in different classes like you do in Qt.

You gain additional design possibilities. For example, if you have a polymorphic container, the class that puts items in it isn't required to outlive the container itself and the classes that read from it. This can be useful in implementing GUIs.

> - Is it common to split new and delete and why in such case, in other projects not involving Qt?

Given the popularity of `boost::shared_ptr<>` and the introduction of `std::shared_ptr<>` in the recent C++ update, there must be some demand for a-symmetric memory management. Both classes implement shared memory ownership based on reference counting.

Comment: Did not know about **std::shared_ptr<>**. So asymmetrical memory management 
is part of the C++ standard. I played with it and true, the copy 
constructor of the shared object is not called, thus is correct to 
write std::shared_ptr<Foo> m_foo(new Foo);. No leaks. The copy 
constructor of the delete object is called however. That is a relief.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it from the opposite direction: why is Bjarne's position a good idea?  Then we can see when it falls apart.

The primary reason for Bjarne's position of symmetrical memory management is that C++ can cause memory leaks if memory ownership is not handled properly.  Bjanrne's position is based on the idea that symmetric memory management increases the likelyhood of developers managing memory properly, and minimizing leaks.

It does this by keeping memory management out of the interactions between classes.  Generally speaking, function calls don't explicitly notate memory management behaviors.  Those tend to be relegated to comments.  Comments can be overlooked.

In the real world, it is not always convenient to do symetric memory management.  For example, any data required to properly manage the memory must have a lifespan as long as the data itself (otherwise it would be invalid when it was needed).  In real life code, developers will cut corners in order to improve readability of their API.

Modern development has seen the introduction of shared_ptr.  shared_ptr solves these issues by putting the memory management rules directly into the function definition, and does so in a way which is so popular amongst developers, that people find few reasons to roll their own.

Shared_ptr meets Bjarne's rule by putting memory management all in one place: shared_ptr, and meets real life needs by allowing ownership of the memory to be passed from place to place.

Comment: Excellent explained, textbook style! You can provide you own delete
and allocate object to shared_ptr. Make sense. The only odd thing with 
std::shared_ptr which I don't understand is why the shared object is 
not copied when initializing shared_ptr. This is asymmetric memory 
management.

Comment: Yes it is.  The reason for that was simply a limitation in C++, mostly due to varargs constructor argument passing.  It just wasn't reasonable to make it 100% symetric.  If you look in C++11 at the new std::make_shared function, it is designed to improve the symmetry by creating the object inside shared_ptr using new syntax only available in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the problem with Bjarne Stroustrups idea about a symmetrical
>   memory management contained within a class?
>
> What do you gain by splitting new and delete so you create an object
>   and destroy it in different classes like you do in Qt.

When you use symmetrical memory management you have to remember if you called "delete" operator on object or not. It increases complexity of programming (which can increase amount of memory leaks) but gives you control over variable's lifecycle. On the other hand if you use some kind of garbage collecting (i.e. like in Java - you can create object but don't handle its deletion) it decreases complexity but sometimes it can lead to problems with performance.

> Is it common to split new and delete and why in such case, in other
>   projects not involving Qt?

Depends on projects. It is question of performance needed for project.

The idea is choice between lower complexity (in case of GC) or higher performance (in case of manual memory management).

P.S. Idea behind garbage collection and passing pointer to some master object is all the same: encapsulation of memory management details. But GC is much better way (you don't have to control if you passed pointer to master object - it is hidden from user, so complexity is lower).

Comment: You don't have to remember whether you deleted the object: Right after you delete it, set the pointer to null and be done. It's true that there might be other pointers around, but then your problem is one of *ownership*, not of memory management.

Comment: You need to put this magic word "delete" always (!) then you want to delete some object. That is what I meant, not checking if object is deleted or not e.g. which you can do setting variable to NULL after using delete and checking if (x == NULL) { ... blah-blah } afterwards. If you forgot to put delete somewhere - it is memory leak. So you should always remember to put "delete" for object somewhere - and so complexity is higher. :)
P.S. Sorry if I've written unclear, English is not my native language.

Comment: @metamaker, uhm... C++ doesn't have garbage collection...

Comment: You can implement one if you really need. See Jeff Alger "C++ for real programmers" for example.

Comment: No, that's not really feasible. It took long enough for Boehm to get anywhere near something that's remotely usable and stable, and it's still far from perfect. You can implement reference counting (or just use a `shared_ptr`) but that's a different matter.

Comment: @metamaker, you certainly can. Except it will only be used by your own code, but not by third-party libraries, which greatly limits its effectiveness. You are much better off using RAII, which generalizes to other types of resources.

Comment: Anyway, the question wasn't about implementing GC in C++ - it was about advantages and disadvantages of QT's approach to memory management which idea is GC-like (as far as I understood from first message of topic).

Comment: @metamaker: That *can* make sense for C, not C++. All the "so called C++ GC" are in fact "C unreachable memory disposers". But a C++ unreachable object is not just a bounch of bit  to be freed: is a object of a class whose destructor has to be called. That requires some information about allocated object to be stored in auxiliary structures of the collectors, that must be C++ aware and not become new / delete global replacement (since C++ containers have to continue to use symmetrical allocation internally).

Comment: @delnan `shared_ptr` is much more efficient way for C++ to deal with memory leaks than GC for sure. But again, you need to put everywhere references to `shared_ptr` class - large coupling leads to problems with compile time and program support if you are going to change `shared_ptr`. Use of GC doesn't increase coupling and it is great advantage of GC.

Comment: @metamaker You're missing my point. GC is *not* feasible to implement as a C++ library. Even less so when you want to use raw pointers instead of some smart pointer.

Comment: @delnan I agree with you that it is bad idea trying to implement GC in C++. If you are programming C++ you are trying to get best performance, otherwise you should better use C#/Java. When I wrote about GC and manual management of memory I concentrated on idea and not implementation. And idea is choice between lower complexity (GC) or higher performance (manual memory management), nothing more.

Comment: Interesting spin of here, the magic of GC. To understand memory management is in my mind of central importance in C++, just because there are _no_ GC. That is why I opened this question to start with. Without understanding of memory how will one be able to do anything in C++ that is useful!

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Qt has been around a long time, and predates C++11 by at least a decade. I would love to see Qt use more modern approaches and to rely more on std:: classes and containers and the like, but that would represent a lot of work on their behalf and break compatibility with the rather large installed code base.

You might consider CopperSpice as an alternative to Qt, which has been modernized.

https://github.com/copperspice

Comment: This looks more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Qt uses different paradigm for memory management (at least in case of `QObject` instances), which is quite natural in its case.

Graphical UIs are typically built as hierarchies of widgets (or controls/views/windows in other toolkits). When a child widget is added to a parent, it is expected to be part of hierarchy until either a) it is explicitly removed from it (in Qt, you can just call `delete` to do this), or b) parent object is destroyed (for example, a top level window is closed by a user).

In other words, in this case parent QObjects control lifetime of their children, and for this reason are responsible for destroying them.

I'd say that symmetrical memory management is a good default approach, but in this particular case, passing ownership to another object seems to be more natural.